# java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am learning to integrate hibernate with spring to connect to Oracle 11g using the below code. But stuck with the same error from few days. Please help me resolve this. i have tried the different solutions mentioned in other answers given for questions with the same error, but no luck.

Any relevant solutions welcome.

Thanks,

Nisha

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="serverDatasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
        <property name="driverClassName" >
            <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url" >
            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.23.225.22:1521:PRACTICE</value>
        </property>
        <!--  <property name="username" value="SCOTT"/>
        <property name="password" value="tiger"/>-->
    </bean> 

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter">
        <property name="targetDataSource" ref="serverDatasource"/>
        <property name="username"><value>SCOTT</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value>tiger</value></property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory bean definition -->
    <bean id="Hibernate5SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.springHibernate.model.Person</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="HibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="personDao" class="com.springHibernate.dao.PersonDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="Hibernate5SessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Main Method: SpringHibernateMain**

```
     package com.springHibernate.main;

        import java.util.List;
        import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
        import com.springHibernate.dao.PersonDao;
        import com.springHibernate.model.Person;

        public class SpringHibernateMain {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

                PersonDao personDao = context.getBean(PersonDao.class);

                Person p = new Person();

                p.setId(1);
                p.setName("John");
                p.setCountry("United States");

                personDao.save(p);

                List<Person> person = personDao.listPerson();

                for(Person p1 : person){
                    System.out.println("Person List:" + p1);
                }

            }

        }
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
ERROR: Unable obtain JDBC Connection
java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:130)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.doGetConnection(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.java:162)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.getConnection(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$3.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:643)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.springHibernate.main.SpringHibernateMain.main(SpringHibernateMain.java:14)

May 16, 2016 12:59:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 17433, SQLState: null
May 16, 2016 12:59:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: invalid arguments in call
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1525)
    at com.springHibernate.dao.PersonDaoImpl.save(PersonDaoImpl.java:25)
    at com.springHibernate.main.SpringHibernateMain.main(SpringHibernateMain.java:24)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:130)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.doGetConnection(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.java:162)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.getConnection(UserCredentialsDataSourceAdapter.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Try moving your username/password properties to the datasource where you configure db url

Comment: I see you are using Oracle 9 dialect, this may be the problem.

Comment: i have tried initially like that only Nadir, was getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this, at last, by adding just the jars in lib/required folder of Hibernate zip file. Till then i had added all the jars in the lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

As It is mentioned in the Stacktrace it is unable to get the connection.

```
invalid arguments in call
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

In datasource driver name should be like below

```
            <value>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</value>
```

Comment: Hi Vijendra, i made the changes u suggested but still facing the same issue

Comment: Hi Nisha can you share your pom.xml file. I tried connecting to my data base using your spring.xm configuration and I am able to get the connection.

Comment: i am not using maven. so i haven't got a pom.xml :|

Comment: I am using org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect but this is not your issue. Your issue is something related to connection url or username/password. if you can write simple connection and try once if it is working.

Comment: with the same connection details i am able to connect to db using hibernate and spring separately. And facing the problem only when i am using the two together

Comment: tried for a different connection as well but no luck again.

Answer (score 2):

In procedure if we give incorrect type mapping from java type to oracle data type then we will get

```java
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for proc SQL state [99999]; error code [17068]; Invalid argument(s) in call; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
```

To fix this we need to map respective data type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
PersonDao personDao = context.getBean(PersonDao.class);
```

Try with

```
PersonDao personDao = (PersonDao) context.getBean("personDao");
```

So your Bean Id in spring.xml

Comment: i debugged the code and found that the error is coming after ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml") 
is executed and before executing the next line which is
PersonDao personDao = context.getBean(PersonDao.class)

Answer (score 0):

if i add -->   "-Duser.language=en"  to debug/run configuration

it works.