# Return last generated key with ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, prepared-statement, resultset

I am trying to execute an insert statement and after execution to obtain the generated id. So far I have made the query and the prepared statement. 
This is part of the code: `PreparedStatement preparedStatement =  connetion.prepareStatement(query.toString(), new String[] {"id"});`
After adding all the parameters I execute this:

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
resultSet.next();
resultSet.getLong(1);
```

The exception that it throws is this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.getNewSql(AutoKeyInfo.java:187)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:4342)
    at com.sirmabc.rfcollection.manager.FeeManagerJDBC.save(FeeManagerJDBC.java:50)
    at com.sirmabc.rfcollection.test.FeeManagerJDBCTest.testSave(FeeManagerJDBCTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

A very important fact is that the code works fine with `ojdbc7`, but as soon as I switch it to work with `ojdbc8` this error occurs.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Similar question was fixed by adding the correct jars in path, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251701/java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-arguments-in-call

Comment: Well not exactly, as you can see I am using directly ojdbc and not hibernate, the post you are suggesting is about the same exception but not the same problem. Here the problem is that these methods no longer work correctly in ojdbc8

Comment: What's your java version?

Comment: It is java 1.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this simple case of one key, you could do:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query.toString(),
    statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

A `new int[] {1}` looks like requiring the ID to be at the first column.
Such it-works solutions might become problematic in the far future.

Unfortunately that the `String[]` version no longer seems to work.

Comment: I have tried your answer, but unfortunately it didn't work. Only the array of integers did the trick.

Comment: Okay I leave my answer as a negative. Maybe soon a repaired version will appear.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the method `prepareStatement(query.toString(), new String[] {"id"});` no longer works for oracle databases. After long hours of bumping my head I found out that the method `prepareStatement(query.toString(), new int[] {1});` works fine. The thing is you need to be careful when using it in oracle, it starts with 1 not with 0 if you put 0 it would again throw an exception for wrong arguments.

Comment: A similar case is documented in the atlassian bug tracker: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-68476 The Oracle Support page they refer to is only partially public, and states that the value of NLS_CHARACTERSET also plays a role.